# how to add right to left animation and zoom in animation using CGAffineTransformScale

Tags: ios, caanimation

I am new to core graphics, I want to show a view from right to left animation using CGAffineTransformScale after completion of this animation I have apply zooming animation to same view.

I can show the right to left animation. But I am unable to show the zooming animation.

Can some one help me to solve the above problem.

Please find the below code what i tried.

```
toView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0.5);
toView.center = CGPointMake(toViewController.view.bounds.size.width,toViewController.view.bounds.size.height/2.0);
toView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -1.0, 1.0);
[UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION delay: 0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{
            [toView setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)];

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scale values are `1.0` that default value, change it to any other value other than `1.0`, may be `1.2` to zoom-in, or `0.8` to zoom out.

And I think there should be few additions to your animation block.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION delay: 0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{
            [toView setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2)]; //Zoom in

 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       if(finished){
         [UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION animations:^{
              toView.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity; //Make things normal.
         }];
       }
 }];
```

I hope it works.

Cheers.